# How to append values to a list using groupby?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.read_json(prices.json, orient = "records")    
df.groupby("Prices")["Discounts"].mean()


Prices
421.0     93.243137
415.0     91.830721
147.0     96.098335
451.0     98.308000
532.0     99.589286
             ...
1333.0    91.655944
7124.0    94.670829
1315.0    97.975439
6316.0    91.800000
1334.0    99.081081
```

I have two questions.

First:

How can I append the values of the "Prices" column to a list? Applying `to_list` method to the code below only appends the average discounts to the list, but I need also to separately extract the first column (Prices) into the list.

```
prices_column = []
discounts_column = []

discounts_column.extend(df.groupby("Prices")["Discounts"].mean().to_list())
```

Second:

How can I round the average discount numbers (second column) to the nearest hundred when appending the values to the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 1],
                   'B': [1010.1112, 1300.009, 749.78, 900.98]})

df_dict = df.groupby('A')['B'].mean().round(2).to_dict()
a_column = list(df_dict.keys())
b_column = list(df_dict.values())
```

with result

```
[1, 2]
[1070.37, 749.78]
```

what you are looking for?

Comment: a_column yields the desired output, but the b_column prints only 100 in my case.

Comment: @Alexander That's probably because the nearest 100 to the means is 100 (for the example values that's definitely the case). Maybe I misunderstood what you mean by "nearest hundred"?

Comment: for example, 100,5678 should be 100,57.

Comment: @Alexander I see. Have updated my answer.